# Containers who overlap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, yii2-advanced-app

So, i tried to use a bootstrap 4.1 theme on my yii2 project. The thing is, it made my containers to overlap like half of their width. The classes that i use are from bootstrap.
Image with the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccisL.jpg
My code and classes:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4" style="text-align:center;">
     <div class="thumbnail">          
         <div class="caption" style="align-items: center;">        
            <img style="width=200 height=300"><?=HtmlPurifier::process($model->thumnail)?></img>
            <h4 class="overme"><?=Html::encode ($model->title)?></h4>
            <p>
               <?=Html::a('More Informations', ['/library/books/detail', 'id' => $model->id], ['class'=>"btn btn-md
 btn-primary"])?>
            </p>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

The site and the theme:
https://bootswatch.com/cerulean/

The bootstrap code of the theme:
https://bootswatch.com/4/cerulean/bootstrap.css

Comment: the problem has to do with  <img style="width=200 height=300">, you give your images a fixed height and width but they are in a container with a dynamic %width

Comment: I had the same witdh and height with the default theme who used bootstrap 3.37 (if i am not wrong) and it was ok. I will try to use % in the image and i will update if it's ok

Comment: Well, i try to use %, but it does not change, i made it smaller, bigger, but the problem remained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<img style="width=200 height=300" src="..." />
```

Into this:

```
<img style="width: 200px; height: auto; max-width: 100%;" src="..." />
```

The first code has invalid CSS. The code also sets a fixed height, while you want a dynamic one, as bootstrap does not provide fixed width containers. The improved code sets the width to '100%' and the height to a value that respects the aspect ratio ('auto'). The maximum width of the image is '200px' (yeah... try to wrap your head around that).

The 'width' says that the image should be '200px' wide, but the 'max-width' value says that the image cannot be larger than '100%' of the first positioned parent (in this case the column). Therefore it can be '200px' in a '400px' column, but it will be '133px' in a '133px' column.

Hope this helps!

Comment: First of all, your explanation is gorgeous and easy to understand! Secondly, the thumbnail class does not adjust to the image size and i don't know why.

Comment: Thank you. The img tag should not have content (only attributes). Did you add a src to the img tag?